# Python AWS CDK - Redshift as destination for kinesis firehose?

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm looking for a way to configure redshift as a destination for kinesis firehose with the aws cdk (python). I'm not seeing any specific documentation on doing this like you can with s3.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-kinesisfirehose-readme.html

I'm looking into [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_kinesisfirehose/CfnDeliveryStream.html#aws_cdk.aws_kinesisfirehose.CfnDeliveryStream.RedshiftDestinationConfigurationProperty), but it seems like a lower level method.

If using this, should I just drop it into the destination field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you have shared seems the right approach.

If you are using typescript, same can be written as below:

```
// The code below shows an example of how to instantiate this type.
// The values are placeholders you should change.
import { aws_kinesisfirehose as kinesisfirehose } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
const cfnDeliveryStream = new kinesisfirehose.CfnDeliveryStream(this, 'MyCfnDeliveryStream', /* all optional props */ {

  deliveryStreamName: 'deliveryStreamName',
  deliveryStreamType: 'deliveryStreamType',

  redshiftDestinationConfiguration: {
    clusterJdbcurl: 'clusterJdbcurl',
    copyCommand: {
      dataTableName: 'dataTableName',

      // the properties below are optional
      copyOptions: 'copyOptions',
      dataTableColumns: 'dataTableColumns',
    },
    password: 'password',
    roleArn: 'roleArn',
    s3Configuration: {
      bucketArn: 'bucketArn',
      roleArn: 'roleArn',

      // the properties below are optional
      bufferingHints: {
        intervalInSeconds: 123,
        sizeInMBs: 123,
      },
      cloudWatchLoggingOptions: {
        enabled: false,
        logGroupName: 'logGroupName',
        logStreamName: 'logStreamName',
      },
      compressionFormat: 'compressionFormat',
      encryptionConfiguration: {
        kmsEncryptionConfig: {
          awskmsKeyArn: 'awskmsKeyArn',
        },
        noEncryptionConfig: 'noEncryptionConfig',
      },
      errorOutputPrefix: 'errorOutputPrefix',
      prefix: 'prefix',
    },
    username: 'username',

    // the properties below are optional
    cloudWatchLoggingOptions: {
      enabled: false,
      logGroupName: 'logGroupName',
      logStreamName: 'logStreamName',
    },
    processingConfiguration: {
      enabled: false,
      processors: [{
        type: 'type',

        // the properties below are optional
        parameters: [{
          parameterName: 'parameterName',
          parameterValue: 'parameterValue',
        }],
      }],
    },
    retryOptions: {
      durationInSeconds: 123,
    },
    s3BackupConfiguration: {
      bucketArn: 'bucketArn',
      roleArn: 'roleArn',

      // the properties below are optional
      bufferingHints: {
        intervalInSeconds: 123,
        sizeInMBs: 123,
      },
      cloudWatchLoggingOptions: {
        enabled: false,
        logGroupName: 'logGroupName',
        logStreamName: 'logStreamName',
      },
      compressionFormat: 'compressionFormat',
      encryptionConfiguration: {
        kmsEncryptionConfig: {
          awskmsKeyArn: 'awskmsKeyArn',
        },
        noEncryptionConfig: 'noEncryptionConfig',
      },
      errorOutputPrefix: 'errorOutputPrefix',
      prefix: 'prefix',
    },
    s3BackupMode: 's3BackupMode',
  },

});
```